# Android - String encoding failed in ListView

Tags: android, string, listview, encoding

I'm using Android Studio lastest version on Windows.
I created dialog using with `DialogFragment`.
This dialog has a `ListView`.

### My codes are below:

```
public class DestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    View rootView;
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    String[] listitems;

    public DestDialogFragment() {
        listitems = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }; // Actually, this array has my real country language strings.

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment_destination, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dest_listview);

        // dialog without title
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitems);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(onClickListItem);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onClickListItem = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mAdapter.getItem(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
}
```

Actually, `listitem[]` has not just like `"a", "b", "c", "d"`.
It has `my real country language strings`.

Anyway, I debugged my project.
And the debugger says `listitem[]` has values like `"????", "??????", "???????", "????"`
That's why I cannot see the right result on device.

So I googled it. I tried to change `File Encoding` in the menu `Settings`
and tried to edit file `build.gradle`. But, these methods are not working for me...

I don't know why... Could you please help me?

Comment: you don't have to apologize for your inglis :) all the time. actually you don't have to at all

Comment: @injecteer Thank you! I clicked something in my Inbox. And my question just has edited automatically without apologizing.

Comment: oh yes, "automatically" ;)

Comment: try this code  ` String[] listitems= new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }; 

    public DestDialogFragment() {
       

    }`

Comment: @devcelebi Thank you for your comment. I tried your code. But, It's not working for me.

Comment: try this String[] listitems={ "a", "b", "c", "d" };  :)

Comment: how to solve this problem? Can you write this solution on your question?

Comment: @devcelebi Sure. I tried _injecteer_'s code of the Answer. I override method `onActivityCreated`. In this method, I write this code. `listitems = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors_array);` `mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitems);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the text labels into the java class at all! Use resource-xml files for that. [read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) to get the idea.

in your code you can put

```
    <string-array name="colors_array">
        <item>White</item>
        <item>Black</item>
        <item>Pink</item>
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Violet</item>
    </string-array>
```

into `res/values-[your lang]/strings.xml` and use it in your java code:

```
String[] array = getContext().getResources().getStringArray( R.array.colors_array );
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array );
```

Comment: Wow. I changed your code as `String[] array = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors_array);` And It's working for me! Thank you!